# How to remove WhiteSpaces using LTRIM and RTRIM to display name?

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql and working with a column name where names are listed with spaces.

**Example: Alan Joe**

I am using LTRIM and RTRIM to display name as 'AlanJoe'

```
select LTRIM(name)
```

Any help how to remove spaces between the names or any links I can learn from?
Thank you

Comment: Use `replace()` if you want to remove spaces inside a string.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Your columns are probably of type `Char(<something>)` instead of `VARChar(<something>)`. Stop using L/R-Trim all-over the place and fix the problem. Edit: may have misunderstood the question. If you want to remove spaces between words, use `replace(field, ' ', '')` as suggested by others.

Comment: Just for clarification. LTRIM (Left Trim) only removes the spaces at the start of a string. While RTRIM (Right Trim) only those at the end of the string. And some DBMS have a TRIM function that does both. F.e. [TRIM in MS SQL Server 2017+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `replace()` function

```
select replace(name,' ','')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with

1. `ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM((FirstName,''),'') + ' ','') + LTRIM(RTRIM((LastName,''),'')`
   this will make FirstName LastName combination with 1 Space if FirstName Value exists else will give only Last Name.
2. For removing the spaces simply use `REPLACE(Name,' ','')`

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the answer?.
As the answer is self explanatory, and  gives more clarity.

Comment: There was mistake of syntax in replace and incorporated in the answer.